# How can we create custom liquid variables within variables (i.e., custom liquid objects)?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

Let us consider the following code:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
test:
  name: google.com
---

{{ post.test.name }}
{% assign addr="https://www.google.com" %}

# Heading
This is a link to [the Google homepage!][ghome]
This is another link that [may or maynot work][glink]


[ghome]: https://google.com
[glink]: {{ addr }}
```

It outputs properly:

[image: Output1]

However, when I try to do the same but change `addr` to `test.addr`
(and thus convert it to a data-member of `test`, the link breaks:

[image: broken object]

1. How do I make the above work?!
2. How can I add a new property to the variable `page.test` which is described in the front-matter of the page?

Comment: What is your code for the second example ? Where do `link` and  `container` come from ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel They're the custom variable and  object (respectively) I'm trying to create..

Comment: Did you want to replace `test.name` by `container.link` ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Im sorry for the confusion, I've clarified my question. By link i meant the variable containing the link, and container was the object `test`.

Comment: You cannot modify objects crated in config or front matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a `Page`, data flows in one direction.

`Front Matter` `=>` `Content`

You can do the following:

```
{% assign addr = page.test.name %}

[link][glink]
[glink]: {{ addr }}
```

But **you can't do the following**:

```
{% assign page.test.addr = "https://www.google.com" %}

[link][glink]
[glink]: {{ page.test.addr }}
```